# Elliptic regularity of weak solutions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-operators

I am looking for a precise reference for this result (I hope it is right).

If $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ weak solution to

$$\Delta u+b(x)\cdot Du+ c(x)u=0$$

where $b\in C^1$ and $c\in C^0$, then $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A classic reference for this question is Gilbarg-Trudinger "Elliptic Partial differential equations of second order", Springer. However, you take as granted the existence of a weak solution, which is not trivial without extra assumptions on $b$ and $c$ (at least $c<0$).

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd look for it in chapter 8 but I did not find it...